# How to send array datatype to server?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am using PHP as server side coding, and i want a set of values to be send to the server(in array format). how can i send that, and retrieve that array value at backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Encode](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php) it as a JSON string and decode it using PHP [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

- Use [JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) (the source is [available here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)) to convert your array to string at JavaScript end.
- Send this string to your PHP page using an `XMLHttpRequest`.
- In the PHP code, read the string from the `$_POST` variable and call `json_encode` on it.

Comment: can you give me the code to send JSON data format using Javascript??

Comment: There is plenty of library to do that available on the Internet. Here are few example :

http://devpro.it/JSON/files/JSON-js.html
http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/json
(etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Send the array as a json string, en then use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: how to send a JSON string using javascript or PHP??

Comment: indeed as above, plenty of javascript libraries that can do that for you, dojo, jquery, prototype etc.. or you create it your self see  http://json.org/ for more info on json